# Does Sun's HotSpot have Objects Inlining optimization?

Tags: jvm, jit

I read somewhere that there is such optimization as Objects Inlining. It collocates two objects together if they have the same life-time scopes and there is a lot of reads between them. And GC also treat them as one to move from one generation to another.

But I didn't find any mention about this optimization on java.sun.com to be sure that HotSpot has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it has. I asked [Charlie Hunt](http://blogs.oracle.com/charliebrown/) personally.